# How to remove all of default speed dials of Opera Mobile?

Tags: browser, opera-browser

Opera Mobile comes with some pre-loaded speed dials which annoy me. So, I remove them all leaving speed dials added by me. But, whenever I restart Opera Mobile after that, those default speed dials are restored. How to counter this?

Comment: Where is it installed?

Comment: @Secko Its on internal SD which can't be removed (unlike external SD).

Comment: Do you use the desktop version of Opera / Opera Mini and have Opera Link enabled for sync?

If it's hardcoded in, though you're SOL.

Comment: @Sparx No, I don't use Opera Link.

Comment: It doesn't restore for me.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Try enabling the EXIT button in settings, then after you change the speed dials to your desired settings, manually exit the browser. Hopefully that will make it save the changes.

Comment: @Sparx :) I always use exit button to exit.

Comment: Have you tried the usual Windows remedy? Uninstall, reboot, fresh install ? ;-). I installed Opera Mobile to test out if the issue was being duplicated. Also, i have opera link and all my speed dials are restored without a hitch.

Comment: @Sparx The problem has been fixed after fresh install. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is gone after a fresh install. Now, there's no need to answer.